# The values I entering is not getting added.Can you find any error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

please find my code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgofZ.jpg).

The values that I enter in textboxes are not getting added to table.

Is there any error?

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the `=` after `app.controller`

Change
`app.controller=('mycont',function($scope){`
to
`app.controller('mycont',function($scope){`